# Highlighting Edges in TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have attached a picture for sample, I want some edges in color as shown in the figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
%usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{pifont}
\title{test}
\author{xyz}
\date{June 2022}

\begin{document}

 \maketitle

\section{Introduction}
 \begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}[mycircle/.style={circle,draw=black, text opacity=1, inner sep=5pt}, myarrow/.style={-Stealth},node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm]
  \node[mycircle] (c1) {$s$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c2) {$v_2$};
  \node[mycircle,right=of c2] (c3) {$v_4$};
  \node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c4) {$v_1$};
  \node[mycircle,right=of c4] (c5) {$v_3$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c5] (c6) {$t$};
 \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
  c1/c2/2:\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
  c1/c4/3:\textcolor{blue}{1}/above,
  c2/c3/3:\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
  c3/c6/2:\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
  c4/c5/2:\textcolor{blue}{2}/above,
  c5/c6/3:\textcolor{blue}{2}/above,
  c5/c2/1:\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
  c3/c5/3:\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
  c2.70/c4.290/3:\textcolor{blue}{1}/below}
   \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\smaller,\p] {\txt} (\j);
\node[below] at (2.75,-2) {(a)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mycircle/.style={circle,draw=black, text opacity=1, inner sep=5pt}, myarrow/.style={-Stealth},node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm]
  \node[mycircle] (c1) {$s$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c2) {$v_2$};
  \node[mycircle,right=of c2] (c3) {$v_4$};
  \node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c4) {$v_1$};
  \node[mycircle,right=of c4] (c5) {$v_3$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=of c5] (c6) {$t$};
 \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
  c2/c1/2/below,
  c1.60/c4.190/2/above,
  c4.210/c1.35/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
  c2.0/c3.180/1/above,
  c3.200/c2.340/\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
  c3/c6/1/above,
  c6.240/c3.10/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
  c5/c4/\textcolor{blue}{2}/above,
  c5.350/c6.110/1/above,
  c6.135/c5.330/\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
  c2/c5/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
  c3.80/c5.280/2/below,
  c5.260/c3.100/\textcolor{blue}{1}/above,
  c4.260/c2.100/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
  c2.80/c4.280/2/below}
   \draw [myarrow] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\smaller,\p] {\txt} (\j);
\node[below] at (2.75,-2) {(b)};


 % draw this outside loop to get proper orientation of 10
 %\draw [myarrow] (c4.260) -- node[sloped,font=\smaller,above,rotate=180] {\textcolor{blue}{1}} (c2.100);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Illustrating a residual network: (a) original network $G$: (b) residual network 
$G_f$. Residual network is define based on a flow (a different flow tends to different 
 residual network).}
```

Comment: One way to do it: split the loop into two (black + red), and put the edges color like this: \draw [myarrow, red]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a variable `\col` in `\foreach` loop to specify the color of draw.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mycircle/.style={circle,draw=black, text opacity=1, inner sep=5pt}, myarrow/.style={-Stealth},node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm]
\node[mycircle] (c1) {$s$};
\node[mycircle,below right=of c1] (c2) {$v_2$};
\node[mycircle,right=of c2] (c3) {$v_4$};
\node[mycircle,above right=of c1] (c4) {$v_1$};
\node[mycircle,right=of c4] (c5) {$v_3$};
\node[mycircle,below right=of c5] (c6) {$t$};
\foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p/\col/\lw in {% start node/end node/text/position/color/lw
c2/c1/2/below/black/0.8pt,
c1.60/c4.190/2/above/red/2pt,
c4.210/c1.35/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below/black/0.8pt,
c2.0/c3.180/1/above/black/0.8pt,
c3.200/c2.340/\textcolor{blue}{2}/below/red/2pt,
c3/c6/1/above/black/0.8pt,
c6.240/c3.10/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below/red/2pt,
c5/c4/\textcolor{blue}{2}/above/black/0.8pt,
c5.350/c6.110/1/above/black/0.8pt,
c6.135/c5.330/\textcolor{blue}{2}/below/black/0.8pt,
c2/c5/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below/black/0.8pt,
c3.80/c5.280/2/below/black/0.8pt,
c5.260/c3.100/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below/black/0.8pt,
c4.260/c2.100/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below/red/2pt,
c2.80/c4.280/2/below/black/0.8pt}
\draw [myarrow,\col,line width=\lw] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,\p,black] {\txt} (\j);
\node[below] at (2.75,-2) {(b)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, dear, could you help me if I wanted to make these red edges bold or highlight them. how can we do this?

Comment: I also wanted to make the font smaller on the edges.

Comment: @wasifahmed you can use `font=` option to set the fontsize, could also add another variable to foreach loop to set the `line width=` option.

Comment: I tried the font function it is not working unfortunately

Comment: @wasif I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Tom's answer is incredible. It uses very well the `foreach` structure in order to customize each individual element of the arrow's set.

There is although a slight contribution I can add while exploring some of the philosophy of how to work with LaTeX and how to organize your own work.

Looking at Tom's answer, I noticed there was some interesting subsets, mainly divided by arrow's type, they are (a) red (b) gray and (c) black arrows. *So instead of defining how each element of the set will behave, why not defining how the whole (sub)set will behave?*

Thinking like this, I define three `scope`s, each one for each arrow subset, and then I could remove some specific instructions in `foreach` to be a common definition of the whole (sub)set. It makes the code a little bit easier to read and to find which line does what where in the figure. One can argue that the division of sets is arbitrary and somehow useless. Which I agree. The paradigm here something like: *Do you want 2 codes with 500 lines each, of 500 codes with 2 lines each?*, I'd prefer 10 codes with 100 lines or 20 codes with 50 lines dividing them accordingly to what fits the problem better.

With this split, it became a little bit easier to find arrows where `left` and `right` should be added to `below` and `above`, to add `\quad` to change the displacement of number in the crossing section in the middle of the diagram, and also to insert `\rotatebox{}` to some nodes to achieve the original proposed format.

Dividing the code into `scope`s also makes simpler to change the set definition. Let's say all red arrows must now be `green`, ok just change the set definition. Although a Find and Replace operation still works fine, changing the set definition is more practical. On the other hand, if a red arrow must become a black arrow, cut and paste its line into the other set.

OBS: I also added `=50pt` at the `node`s definition to spread nodes afar and one number is orange.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mycircle/.style={circle,draw=black, text opacity=1, inner sep=5pt},
  myarrow/.style={-Stealth},node distance=0.6cm and 1.2cm]
  \node[mycircle] (c1) {$s$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=50pt of c1] (c2) {$v_2$};
  \node[mycircle,right=50pt of c2] (c3) {$v_4$};
  \node[mycircle,above right=50pt of c1] (c4) {$v_1$};
  \node[mycircle,right=50pt of c4] (c5) {$v_3$};
  \node[mycircle,below right=50pt of c5] (c6) {$t$};
  \begin{scope}[red]
    \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
      c1.60/c4.190/5/above,
      c2.340/c3.200/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
      c3.10/c6.260/\textcolor{blue}{3}/below,
      c4.260/c2.100/\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor{blue}{1}}/below}
    \draw [myarrow,line width=2pt] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,\p] {\txt} (\j);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[black]
    \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
      c2/c1/2/above,
      c2/c5/\quad \quad \textcolor{orange}{1}/above right,
      c2.80/c4.280/\rotatebox{-90}1/below,
      c3.180/c2.0/1/above,
      c4.210/c1.35/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below,
      c4.340/c3.110/\quad 1/above right,
      c4.10/c5.170/\textcolor{blue}{2}/above,
      c5.190/c4.350/\textcolor{blue}{2}/below,
      c5.350/c6.110/1/above,
      c6/c3/3/above,
      c6.135/c5.330/\textcolor{blue}{1}/below}
    \draw [myarrow,line width=0.8pt] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,\p] {\txt} (\j);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[gray]
    \foreach \i/\j/\txt/\p in {% start node/end node/text/position
      c1.280/c2.160/0/below,
      c3.130/c4.310/0\quad\quad/below left,
      c5.260/c2.30/0\quad\quad/below left}
    \draw [myarrow,line width=0.8pt] (\i) -- node[sloped,font=\tiny,\p] {\textcolor{gray}\txt} (\j);
  \end{scope}
  
  \node[below] at (2.75,-2.5) {(b)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]